# How to output result of a mysql query as a json file in node.js

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

What i have her is this

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res){
  connection.connect();
  email = req.body.email;
  password = req.body.password;
  if(email && password ) {
    console.log(email);
    console.log(password);
   // connection.query('SELECT username FROM user WHERE email =? and password = ?', [email, password], 
   // function (error, rows, fields) { 
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM user ', 
    function (error, rows, fields) {
      var str='';
      for (var i = 0;i < rows.length; i++) {
        str = str + rows[i].username;
        res.end(str);
      }
      connection.end(); 
    }); 
  }
});
```

so instead of just displaying the result i want it to be something like this:

```
{
 "username": "ABC",
 "username": "DEF",
 "username": "HIJ"
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify? which query are you trying to execute? It seems like the commented out query is the one you want? And the output you want isn't possible. You cant have the same key on a single object.

Comment: just modified it,any help?

Comment: Hint: JSON.stringify :)

Comment: Makes more sense, but the output you are expecting is not possible. an array of usernames like `['ABC', 'DEF', 'HIJ']` can work though.

Comment: could you please show me how to do that,i tried JSON.stringify(str) it just puts the str between double quotes now i want it as an array

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first problem is you're not actually building the object you want. The second problem is you're not building an array of them. Finally, you need to convert that array into JSON if the `res` object doesn't have something like `res.json`.

```
var objs = [];
for (var i = 0;i < rows.length; i++) {
    objs.push({username: rows[i].username});
}
connection.end();
res.end(JSON.stringify(objs));
```

Answer (score -3):

With Express 4.x, the output rows from mysql db is in json format.

For example, look at this

```js
sqlConnect.connection.query('SELECT * from users', function(err, rows, fields){
  if (err)
  {
   console.log("Querying error");
  }
  else
  {
   console.log(rows);
  }
  sqlConnect.connection.end();
 });
});
```

The output is of the form

```css
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    username: 'shivkanth',
    password: '1q2w3e4r',
    verified: 0 } ]
```

So now you can get the individual values using the . operator. For example, console.log(rows[0].username)  will log the value 'shivkanth'